Macro function indirection
I'm trying to write a macro for a formatting library of sorts. The idea is you can use a mix of string literals, regular functions, and (this is where I get stuck) inferred/scoped functions. I suspect I could get this working with proc macros, but that's more complicated, and I'd like to keep the code for the macro easier to read if possible.
Example
Here is a trimmed down version of the code that I'm writing.
enum TemplateEntry<T> {
    Text(String),
    Typed(T, String),
}

enum ColorType {
    Red(String),
    Blue(String),
}

impl ColorType {
    pub fn red(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self::Red(s.to_string())
    
    pub fn blue(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self::Blue(s.to_string())
    }
}

impl Into<TemplateEntry<ColorType>> for ColorType {
    fn into(&self) -> TemplateEntry<Self> {
        match self {
            Self::Blue(text) => TemplateEntry::Typed(self.clone(), text.clone()),
            Self::Red(text) => TemplateEntry::Typed(self.clone(), text.clone()),
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! markup_helper {
    ($temp_vec:ident,  $type_id:tt, @ $x:expr) => {{
        $temp_vec.push($type_id::$x);
    }};
    ( $temp_vec:ident, $type_id:tt, $x:expr) => {{
        $temp_vec.push($x.into());
    }};
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! markup {
    ( $type_id:tt, $( $($opt:literal)? $rest:expr ),* ) => {
        {
            let mut temp_vec: Vec<TemplateEntry<$type_id>> = Vec::new();
            $(
                markup_helper!(temp_vec, $type_id, $($opt)? $rest);
            )*
            temp_vec
        }
    };
}

fn example_call() {
    let _example = markup!(ColorType, "regular text", @blue("other text"), "more regular text", regular_func_returning_text());
    // What I want it to expand to
    let _example = {
        let mut temp_vec: Vec<TemplateEntry<ColorType>> = Vec::new();
        temp_vec.push("regular text".into());
        temp_vec.push(ColorType::blue("other text"));
        temp_vec.push("more regular text".into());
        temp_vec.push(regular_func_returning_text().into());
        temp_vec
    };
}

The @ lookup doesn't work properly because the compiler can't tell if string literals are the optional literal or the expression. Also, it doesn't seem to forward the @ to the helper if I try to parse it with a recursively defined macro.
Reframed Questions
Is there a way I can leverage use to try and look up associated functions on the base type maybe without the @ indicator?
Is there something obvious I'm missing for getting @ or really any other handy indicator symbol to work that would allow a macro like this to work?

It isn't clear to me what you want/expect that macro invocation to expand to?

The main problem is you're not matching the @ the blue or the parentheses in @blue("other text") it's also unclear what you want that to mean.

I've updated the question with what I want the macro to expand to. I expect $rest:expr to match the blue("other text") portion which it seems to when writing less complex macros for experimentation

Please edit your question to include some example inputs and what you expect them to expand to.

@blue is not a literal. It's an @ symbol followed by an ident so it should be parsed as $(@ $opt:ident)?

What you have shown as your desired macro expansion won't compile, for a bunch of reasons.  I'd ask that you fix that first so that we can be sure we understand what you want.  However perhaps something like this is what you're after?

@eggyal's example does what I want. Thank you for putting it together and working through my poorly explained question. The syntax of the macro seems a bit overly complex so I'll try reducing it down and put up an answer with that in it. If you want to put it up yourself, I'd be happy to accept it.

One simplification could be to change the @  rule so that it only expands that character: see example.  Otherwise very happy for you to simplify further as you like and post as an answer.

Thanks to @eggyal, here is the final version I ended up with, which is almost entirely what they provided, just refactored for my own personal preferences.
macro_rules! markup_internal {
    // Expand leading `@` into `$type_id::`
    (($temp_vec:ident:$type_id:ident): [@ $($rest:tt)*]) => {
        markup_internal!(($temp_vec:$type_id): [$type_id::$($rest)*])
    };

    // Handle all other entries
    (($temp_vec:ident:$type_id:ident): [$expr:expr$(, $($rest:tt)*)?]) => {
        // Actually append the entries
        $temp_vec.push($expr.into());
        // Recursively expand
        $(markup_internal!(($temp_vec:$type_id): [$($rest)*]))?
    };
    
    // Supports trailing commas
    (($temp_vec:ident:$type_id:ident): []) => {}
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! markup {
    // set up the array and push each list item into it by recursively invoking this macro
    ($type_id:ident: [$($rest:tt)*]) => {{
        let mut temp_vec = Vec::<TemplateEntry<$type_id>>::new();
        markup_internal!((temp_vec:$type_id): [$($rest)*]);
        temp_vec
    }};
}

